# Simon Says For Loop String Comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop

I've been trying to understand for loops, and for the program I am supposed to write I have to use for loops.

here are the instructions: "Simon Says" is a memory game where "Simon" outputs a sequence of 10 characters (R, G, B, Y) and the user must repeat the sequence. Create a for loop that compares the two strings. For each match, add one point to user_score. Upon a mismatch, end the game. Ex: The following patterns yield a user_score of 4:

simonPattern: R, R, G, B, R, Y, Y, B, G, Y

userPattern:  R, R, G, B, B, R, Y, B, G, Y

to start I am given this:

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = 'RRGBRYYBGY'
user_pattern  = 'RRGBBRYBGY'
print('User score:', user_score)
```

I have passed the first "test" with this code:

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = 'RRGBRYYBGY'
user_pattern  = 'RRGBBRYBGY'
for simon_pattern in str(simon_pattern):
    for user_pattern in str(user_pattern):
        if str(simon_pattern) == str(user_pattern):
            user_score += 1
            continue
        if str(simon_pattern) != str(user_pattern):
            break
print('User score:', user_score)
```

the problem is when it goes to do the second test my output is still User score: 4 instead of User score: 7 (the strings for simon_pattern and user_pattern change for the second test.)

I know I need to compare each element in the string to each other one at a time and add +1, and as soon as two elements don't match my loop needs to stop. I have tried:

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = 'RRGBRYYBGY'
user_pattern  = 'RRGBBRYBGY'
for s in simon_pattern:
    for u in user_pattern:
        if simon_pattern [0] == user_pattern [0]:
            user_score += 1
        if simon_pattern [0] != user_pattern [0]:
            break
        if simon_pattern [1] == user_pattern [1]:
            user_score += 1
        if simon_pattern [1] != user_pattern [1]:
            break
```

(and then I continue the above loops until I get to [9] and print the user_score, but that doesn't work, either.)

I've tried comparing len(simon_pattern) to len(user_pattern) but that just throws back an error telling me that it can't perform that function because I have strings and not integers.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show the exact error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have a much easier time using an index :

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = 'RRGBRYYBGY'
user_pattern  = 'RRGBBRYBGY'
for i in range(len(simon_pattern)):
    if user_pattern[i] == simon_pattern[i]:
        user_score += 1
```

Comment: Specifically, be careful not to overwrite your variables with different meanings. You have `user_pattern` as both their pattern string and you use that name for each letter in the pattern (similar for `simon_pattern`).

Comment: So, I tried this exactly as you wrote it, and it didn't work. My output was User_score: 2 for the first test.

Comment: Okay, I had a typo in the code that I used that you suggested. Once I fixed it, it worked. Thank you so much! Now I'm going to see if I can figure out why that worked over what I was doing, so I can remember this set-up in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your second attempt code (`for s in simon_pattern ...`) is that you were comparing every `s` in `simon_pattern` to every `u` in `user_pattern`). You need to correlate these (usually with an index) so that you only compare the first to the first, second to the second etc.

Comment: So what you're saying is that i stands for index?

Comment: `i` is just a name. Conceptually, you're using it as an index. But, using a short, meaningless name like `i` or `ii` (or `x`, or whatever) usually hints to other programmers that it's just something temporary.

Comment: The key concept of the "index" is that you're tracking the matching position in both strings: "first position, second position" etc.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that. I hadn't attempted to use i simply because (from what I understand from my teacher and from the online textbook) the variable before the assigned variable is just a place-holder and can be anything you want it to be. I think that has tripped me up and only confused me more as I've continued on.

Comment: Yes, it can be whatever you like, although weird things can happen if you use a variable name you've used elsewhere. If nothing else, this will confuse programmers.

Comment: That makes sense. My husband has been trying to help me, but he knows C# and he's had a hard time understanding python. I've been trying to get a handle on how it works with what feels like little explanation. But having a common placeholder, that other programmers recognize, makes sense for uniformity and avoiding confusion. Less confusion is always nice.

Comment: In case you're new to SO, don't forget to up-vote answers, comments etc that helped. :)

Comment: I've been trying to do that. I'm so new it won't let me up-vote, but your help has been deeply appreciated :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying, maybe all you can do is mark it as an answer or nothing at all. Idk.

Answer (score 1):

Using index to iterate through each loop you need some number that increases as you go through each iteration. you can just use user_score since it is already assigned to 0, and going to increase after each iteration by 1. You will probably say "but it is going to be increased only if there is a match!" (this is right)! but if there is mismatch you are going to break out of the loop anyways, and end the game so this it's a perfect.

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern  = input()

for i in simon_pattern:
   if user_pattern[user_score] == simon_pattern[user_score]:
      user_score += 1
   else:
      break
            

print('User score:', user_score)
```

Comment: Using index to iterate through each loop you need some number that will be increase as you go through each iteration, and for this purpose you can just use user_score since it is already assigned to 0, and going to increase after each iteration by 1. You will probably say "but it is going to be increased only if there is a match!", this is right)! but if there is mismatch you going to break out of the loop anyways, and end the game so this is a perfect feet!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64934022/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern  = input()

for i in range(len(simon_pattern)):    # loop for each letter in simon_pattern
    if user_pattern[i] == simon_pattern[i]:    # if user matches simon
        user_score += 1    # add 1 to the user_score
    else:    # otherwise exit the game
        break

print('User score:', user_score)    #output final score
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it with continues and breaks like I had to, it would be something like this:

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern  = input()

for i in range(len(simon_pattern)):
    if user_pattern[i] == simon_pattern[i]:
        user_score += 1
        continue
    else:
        break
print('User score:', user_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern = input()
x = 0
for n in simon_pattern:
    if n == user_pattern[x]:
        x += 1
        user_score += 1
    else:
        break

print(f'User score: {user_score}')
```

Answer (score 0):

the "most useful" answer above is missing the break which will cause the tests to fail.  Use the code below to pass all the tests.  As many people suggested, using an index is your best bet and gives you the cleanest code as well.

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern  = input()
for i in range(len(simon_pattern)):
    if user_pattern[i] == simon_pattern[i]:
        user_score += 1
    else:
        break

print('User score:', user_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it is lacking a good answer, so ...

Using just a simple `for` loop:

```
simon_pattern = 'RRGBRYYBGY'
user_pattern  = 'RRGBBRYBGY'

idx = 0  # index counter
score = 0

for ch in simon_pattern:  # iterate through string
    if ch == user_pattern[idx]:  # compare with the corresponding user character
        score += 1
    else:
        break
    idx += 1  # Increment index before next loop

print(f'Score = {score}')
```

but better would be to [enumerate](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_enumerate.asp) the loop:

```
simon_pattern = 'RRGBRYYBGY'
user_pattern  = 'RRGBBRYBGY'
score = 0

for idx, ch in enumerate(simon_pattern):
    if ch != user_pattern[idx]:  # break out if they don't match
        break
    score += 1

print(f'Score = {score}')
```

but best would be to iterate over both strings simultaneously with [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp):

```
simon_pattern = 'RRGBRYYBGY'
user_pattern  = 'RRGBBRYBGY'
score = 0

for simon_ch, user_ch in zip(simon_pattern, user_pattern):
    if simon_ch != user_ch:
        break
    score += 1

print(f'Score = {score}')
```

Answer (score -1):

This code worked perfectly fine to pass all the test for my zybooks assignment.

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern  = input()


for i in range(len(simon_pattern)):
    if simon_pattern[i] == user_pattern[i]:
        user_score += 1
        i += 1
    elif simon_pattern[i] != user_pattern[i]:
        break
            

print(f'User score: {user_score}')
```